# How to correctly setup latest LWJGL libraries to Eclipse?

Tags: opengl, java, lwjgl, eclipse

A year ago, I understood how to setup an LWJGL project in Eclipse IDE.
Now LWJGL has a lot of changes including a different file structure.
I downloaded the latest release, LWJGL **3.1.0** Build 40 from the official site.

There's also a page explaining how to get started, but it does not help me to set it up in Eclipse.
When I extract the downloaded `.zip` file, I only get `.jar` files (and `.txt` licences).
I see nowadays there are no `.dll` natives for a specific operating system.

Instead of that, I see jars like `lwjgl-glfw-natives-windows.jar`. I expect these are now the files that were previously `.dll` files.

Can someone explain to me how to set it all up correctly?

Answer (score 2):

You can create gradle or maven project and add dependencies which you can generate on [lwjgl download page](https://www.lwjgl.org/download).

Another way - you can download jar

[image: download configuration]

Create simple Java project in eclipse, create folder in project called for example `lib` and put all jars from archive to this folder

[image]

After that go to Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add JARs... and select all jars from this folder.

[image]

Create class HelloWorld from [Get started guide](https://www.lwjgl.org/guide)
and run it. Done.

Answer (score 2):

I've had to do this multiple times as of recent: here's my method.

First, head over to the [LWJGL homepage](https://www.lwjgl.org/), and click on the DOWNLOAD tab up at the top.

[image: LWJGL homepage]

After that, click "Customize LWJGL 3"

[image: Customize]

From there, select "Release", and click on the modules, modes, natives and presets you want. I usually get the ZIP Bundle with Windows natives and everything included, along with JOML. Hit "DOWNLOAD ZIP" at the bottom, and extract it to anywhere you please.

[image]

Now, open up your project in Eclipse, and create a new folder called "lib" or "library". From there, get your extracted JARs from your extracted ZIP file, and put 'em in.

[image: ddd]

From there, click on your project and hit Alt+Enter to bring up the properties menu. Inside there, click on Java Build Path, then "Add JARs..."

[image]

Click on your lib or library file, and select the ones you need, then hit OK.

Congratulations! You've now set up LWJGL 3 in Eclipse! Now it's time to create your src directory and start coding.

As for the natives that used to be `.dll` files back in LWJGL 2, they've changed them all to `.jar` files (yeah, it threw me off, too when I made the switch).

(If I didn't explain it well enough, [here's the tutorial I used](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VH9KAhjXVFM))